# Why does my Discord bot never gets ready?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot using discord.js, the thing is, the discord never gets ready since he never logs anything in the console, here's the script:

```
import DiscordJS, { IntentsBitField } from 'discord.js'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
    ]
})

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("W")
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

Even though I have the token and all, it never gets ready cuz it never prints "W" in the console, any ideas why it doesn't work? (I'm using typescript btw)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no difference about `typescript` with normal calling with packages,
then on this line:

```js
import DiscordJS, { IntentsBitField } from 'discord.js'
```

since you're importing it should be like:

```js
import { IntentsBitField, DiscordJS } from 'discord.js'
```

And take note that there's no `DiscordJS`. Second, You didn't call the `Client` on this line:

```js
const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
    ]
})
```

You need to add `Client` on your importing, something like:

```js
import { IntentsBitField, Client } from 'discord.js'
```

And update your:

```js
const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
    ]
})
```

to

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
    ]
})
```

And I think adding `partial` on your `new Client` will help the bot to reach out the channels and the guild.

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
    ],
     partials: [Partials.GuildMember, Partials.Channel]
})
```

Look for other way if I missed something. I'm not into typescript
[Here's the link](https://sabe.io/tutorials/how-to-build-discord-bot-typescript)

Comment: Thank you for your refactoring :D